# Please explain the behaviour of the shell (supposed to be csh)

Tags: shell, csh

On my Linux box, `echo $SHELL` results in `/bin/csh`. So I assume my default shell is c-shell. I am trying to understand the behavior of a shell script.
scenario 1 - script contains -

```
echo $1 $2 $3
echo $*
echo $argv[1] $argv[2]
$argv[3]
echo $argv[*]
echo $#argv
```

output -

```
arg1 arg2 arg3
arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
[1] [2]
./test.sh: line 4: [3]: command not found
[*]
4argv
```

- So clearly the c-shell is not able to execute the last 4 lines in the script which should be executed by csh.

However - when I add the shebang line `#!/bin/csh` at the top of the script, it prints all the output correctly.

Question - Why is the csh not executing the last 4 lines correctly in first scenario and why do I explicitly have to include the shebang line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the file starts with `#!/bin/csh`, you explicitly tell the kernel to run the script with that program. But if there's no `#!` at the start of your file, execution fails – the exec() syscall fails – and your shell attempts to run the script using an even older method, by passing the file directly to `/bin/sh`.

The Bourne shell, `sh`, implemented this behavior way before `#!` appeared, and so scripts written this way expect to be run under `sh` or at least a compatible shell. csh is *far* from compatible, so it runs such scripts under *sh*. Your $SHELL is irrelevant.

[tcsh](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=csh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html):

> Because many systems use either the standard version 6  or  ver-
>   sion  7   shells whose shell scripts are not compatible with this shell,
>   the shell uses such a 'standard' shell to execute a script whose  first
>   character is not a '#', i.e., that does not start with a comment.